# How to write a csv file on Azure Databricks Workspace

Tags: azure, csv, databricks

I'm using a notebook on Azure Databricks, this notebook is in my user repo. I want to write a csv file created by this notebook in this repo.
When i'm using the code below :

df_pandas.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, header=False)

There is no error but the file is not written is the notebook's repo.

Does someone has a clue ?

I've tried to write the complete path or just the csv name but the it still the same error :

Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '/Users/*********/repo_one/repo_two'

Comment: try this and let me know

Comment: notebook_path = f"/Users/<Your-user-name>/notebook/test.csv"

dbutils.fs.put(notebook_path, df_spark.toPandas().to_csv(index=False, header=False), True)

Comment: file_content = dbutils.fs.head(notebook_path)
print(file_content)

Answer (score 0):

- I created a sample Pandas dataframe df_pandas with two columns "**name**" and "**age**" and three rows of data. Then,I am writing the Spark dataframe to a CSV file named "test.csv" in the Databricks file
  system (DBFS)
- The `toPandas()` method is used to convert the Spark dataframe to a Pandas dataframe, and the to_csv() method is used to convert the Pandas dataframe to a CSV string. The `dbutils.fs.put()` method is used to write the CSV string to the specified file path in DBFS.

The below is the code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pandas as pd
data = {'name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Bob'], 'age': [25, 30, 35]}
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas)
dbutils.fs.put("/Users/Dilip/repo_one/repo_two/test.csv", df_spark.toPandas().to_csv(index=False, header=False), True)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]